# Force fusioncharts rendering outside viewport

Tags: export, render, viewport, fusioncharts

I have several Fusioncharts on my page and some of them are outside the viewport.
Usually, they render as soon as the user scrolls the page and make them visible.

Now, I have to export all those charts and, so, I need them to be rendered before starting the export process: is there a way to force the rendering without asking the user to scroll the page down?

Comment: This is an issue with Flash Player and not with FusionCharts. Flash movies do not render when outside veiwport. There is no way to render these charts as of now without using some hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a hack would be to use JavaScript to scroll to bottom and then again to top before exporting.